# What is the difference in authoringKey and endpointKey in luis while developing bot?

Tags: botframework, bots, chatbot

I would appreciate if someone can explain difference in authoringKey and endpointKey. Could not find any details explaining different json properties and where to find them.

```
  "luis": {
"authoringEndpoint": "",
"authoringRegion": "",
"defaultLanguage": "",
"endpoint": "",
"environment": "",
"name": "",
"authoringKey": "",
"endpointKey": ""
```

},

Answer (score 0):

I can answer your question directly, but I can't help with your code in context without some more information about where you are pulling this LUIS object from, which platform you are using for development, and what exactly you are trying to set up.

For a fully functional LUIS app, you need to have both an Authoring resource and a Prediction resource. Each of these come with their own API keys. The Authoring resource is what you use to create your LUIS apps. You can have more than one app on an authoring resource. I believe there is a test key you can use for predictions, but it is very limited and should not be used for production. That's where the Prediction key comes in. That essentially is what allows you to query your LUIS app (it doesn't hold the LUIS models directly). You can have more than one Prediction key associated with an app (e.g. I have one LUIS app for all environments but separate prediction keys for QA and PROD) and you can use a prediction key (I think) across multiple apps.

Even while developing, I recommend having a prediction key and not trying to use the test key provided with the Authoring resource. There is a Free tier Prediction key which supports up to 10K transactions a month. If your volume is low you could even use this for PROD, though I recommend using a paid tier in that case to avoid LUIS potentially shutting off if you hit your quota.